# How to set an automatic reply in SharePoint when a user updates, saves or closes a page?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can anyone give me some idea about how to create an automated reply when a user updates, edits or saves a form in a list in SharePoint?

I am using Sharepoint designer 2007 and SharePoint WSS 2.0.

When the Newform is saved and closed, is it possible to have an automatic reply sent to the "Created By" individual?

Below is the message which should be sent out to the user when any action event is happening on the form

> This is an automatic reply to confirm that your message has been
>   received by the “CustCareAur, OLR” mailbox.  Your message will be
>   reviewed and you will receive a follow up email from the OLR Procedure
>   Team.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a OOTB designer workflow with a simple step of "Send an Email" Action. Configure the "Send an Email" activity to send email to Created By(Author) of the item. Set the workflow to start when ever user Add/Edit item in list.Please see below link how to send email in designer 2007

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx